# How to use Firebug's debugger functions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, debugging, firebug

I don't have an experience with any debugger tools geared towards my language, but I recently found some videos showcasing Firebug.

I'm now using Firebug on a script in which I included an error.

My current understanding is:

- I can set a breakpoint, which is shown as a red circle.
- Firebug stops at the breakpoint and gives me 4 options (Continue, Step Into, Step Over and Step Out).

But I don't understand:

- What the difference is between the 4 options:

`Continue`, `Step Into`, `Step Over` and `Step Out`?

To me, Step Over is sometimes similar to Step Into... I could be wrong here.

I would be grateful if you could explain the differences of the 4 options, or a link to a more in depth explanation on these options.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- `Continue` <kbd>F8</kbd>- Resume execution as if the code was never stopped
- `Step Into` <kbd>F11</kbd> - Change the debugger context to run *into* the function the code is stopped on. If the code cannot step into the function, this is the same as `Step Over`
- `Step Over` <kbd>F10</kbd>- Execute the code the debugger is stopped on, but stay within the current function
- `Step Out` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> - Execute code until the end of the current function, and resume debugging once it has returned

These terms apply to all debuggers. Here is perhaps a better (or at least, more complete) explanation: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/33/debugging/4/

Comment: What do you mean by the current function in the context of JavaScript? `function` is used in many purposes in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes it is, but a function is ultimately just a block of code - so for example when you "step into" a function the debugger will take you to the first line of code in that function. So if I set a breakpoint on a call to `myfunction()`, the debugger breaks, and I click `step into`, the debugger jumps to the first line of `myfunction`. Or if I click `step over`, the debugger just goes to the next line.