# Json array of objects : $.each causes "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I have been spending days trying to figure out why I can't enumerate through the Json result of an Ajax query.  Have got this to work a number of times before but this time it keeps failing when applying $.each.

```
$.ajax({type: 'GET', url: "/api/RestaurantApi/BindRestaurants/?data=",
    data: request,dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index,values) {
    ....
```

My WebApi method is as follows, note the [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] which saves having to put

```
  var jsdata = JSON.parse(data);
```

into the Javascript.

Also I simplified the data so that all properties except the RestaurantID return the same simple values, just in case some unusual character was causing problems.

```
    [Route("BindRestaurants")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public IEnumerable<Restaurant> BindRestaurants()
    {
        dynamic queryJson = ParseHttpGetJson(Request.RequestUri.Query);
        string City= Guid.Parse(queryJson.City.Value);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBConn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "QryRestaurantsforCity";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CityID", City);
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    List<Restaurant> listRestaurants  = new List<Restaurant>();
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Restaurant dm = new Restaurant ();
                            dm.RestaurantID = new Guid(dt.Rows[i]["RestaurantID"].ToString());
                            dm.RestaurantName = "dishesnames";
                            dm.RestaurantTypeID = 15;
                            dm.RestaurantTypeName = "wwwwwww";
                            dm.SortOrder = 1;
                            listRestaurants.Insert(i, dm);
                        }
                    }
                    return (IEnumerable<Restaurant>)listRestaurants;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The result looks entirely normal when examining "data" in Javascript, an array of 9 objects as I have used before:

```
Array[9]

0: Object

RestaurantID: "666a6d14-a62b-4d60-b16e-43005a85047e"

RestaurantName: "restaurantnames"

RestaurantTypeID: 15

RestaurantTypeName: "wwwwwww"

SortOrder: 1

1: Object
2: Object
....
8: Object
```

On the line

```
 $.each(data, function (index,values) {
```

the error it produces:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

suggests it's not an array but a test of the type shows it is.  I tried switching it to an array of arrays using the following...

```
var ArrayofArrays = $.map(data, function (n, i) {
   return [[n.RestaurantID, n.RestaurantName, n.RestaurantTypeID, n.RestaurantTypeName]];
});
```

but the same error occurs.

What am I doing wrong?  My code looks exactly the same as what I have used other times.

Edit: the stringified Json returned is as follows:

```
[  
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"666a6d14-a62b-4d60-b16e-43005a85047e",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   },
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"061eabcb-38cb-4c78-b26a-e9f626e89233",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   },
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"6c328be5-2132-46bc-8469-0aa074eaff11",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   },
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"b51f2b72-8ec6-40e7-9bc7-8e8db3d10bef",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   },
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"c2ab8f02-6b2a-4490-ac67-7843ad6cf083",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   },
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"807a6c3a-ecc8-478f-be05-892104c5668c",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   },
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"1a81c304-b264-48fb-81f9-a5dc10c7fcb8",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   },
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"3b45b85e-cb28-4e23-ae33-6b2ce622b525",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   },
   {  
      "SortOrder":1,
      "RestaurantID":"94153e81-bce1-4a00-b8a0-d897bfad7b0a",
      "RestaurantName":"dishesnames",
      "RestaurantTypeID":15,
      "RestaurantTypeName":"wwwwwww"
   }
]
```

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: can you please show the stringified version of your json?

Comment: seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/NLnY2/

Comment: What language is that backend code?

Comment: Your most important line of code is missing - where is `.length` actually called? I guess it's not on `data` itself but rather some subobject.

Comment: @Christoph It's called internally by `$.each`.

Comment: The error implies that `data` is undefined.

Comment: In the case you're sure data in not undefined, then I would use firebug to step into the internal methods that are executing. That can be a painful process but you said its been days so I figure its worth it at this point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477409/how-to-use-firebugs-debugger-functions

Comment: What happens when you console.log data.length?

Comment: Have found out JS reported the error far from where it actually was. There was no issue with the array at that point but stepping through each line of code, at that point actually stepped through everything in the whole $.each loop so it was generating the error much further down but annoyingly showing the error against the first line.  Once I found that out it was just a matter of putting a debugger statement in the loop and stepping through. Javascript isn't the best language at giving you clear error information.  Thanks for your comments on this.